# Como deletar arquivos e pastas recursivamente de modo seguro com Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, segurança, sistema-de-arquivos

Galera, estou tentando criar um script para deletar meus arquivo e pastas de modo seguro, assim como faz o **shred**, **srm**, etc...mas eu gostaria de fazer isso com script Python. Eu consegui achar uma função na internet que grava valores aleatórios no arquivo antes de deletar ele. Sei que não existe nada irrecuperável, mas como didática gostaria de implementar um script assim.

Tenho essa função:

```py
def secure_delete(file_, steps=3):
    import os
    with open(file_, "ba+", buffering=0) as f:
        data = f.tell()
    f.close()
    with open(file_, "br+", buffering=0) as f:
        for i in range(steps):
            f.seek(0, 0)
            f.write(os.urandom(data))
        f.seek(0)
        for _ in range(data):
            f.write(b'\x00')
    os.remove(file_)
```

Passando o arquivo como argumento, consigo fazer a ação, mas eu gostaria de fazer isso recursivamente em um diretório para todos os arquivos e não abrindo um arquivo especifico ou passando ele como argumento.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, pegando esse exemplo você pode fazer assim:

```py
import os
import shutil
import uuid

def recursive_listing(path):
    files = []

    # r = root, d = directories, f = files
    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        for file in f:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
        for dirs in d:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, dirs))

    list_ = [file for file in files]
    return list_


def secure_delete_recursive(path, steps=5):

    objects = recursive_listing(path)

    for obj in objects:
        # Para arquivos (gravando, renomeando e deletando)
        if os.path.isfile(obj):
            try:

                with open(obj, "ba+", buffering=0) as f:
                    data = f.tell()
                f.close()

                with open(obj, "br+", buffering=0) as f:
                    for i in range(steps):
                        f.seek(0, 0)
                        f.write(os.urandom(data))
                    f.seek(0)
                    for _ in range(data):
                        f.write(b'\x00')

                name = str(uuid.uuid4())
                new_file_rename = os.path.join(os.path.split(obj)[0], name)
                os.rename(obj, new_file_rename)
                # Descomente a linha abaixo para deletar os arquivos recursivamente.
                # os.remove(new_file_rename)

            except PermissionError as p:
                print(p)

    for obj in objects:
        # Para diretórios (renomeando e deletando)
        if os.path.isdir(obj):
            try:

                name = str(uuid.uuid4())
                new_file_rename = os.path.join(os.path.split(obj)[0], name)
                os.rename(obj, new_file_rename)
                # Descomente a linha abaixo para deletar as pastas recursivamente.
                # shutil.rmtree(new_file_rename, ignore_errors=False, onerror=None)

            except PermissionError as p:
                print(p)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    secure_delete_recursive('/tmp')
```

Você também pode usar o biblioteca [Cryptography](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/) com essa mesma ideia desse exemplo acima, fica até mais seguro do que gravar binários ou, você pode usar as duas formas juntas que reforma mais ainda. Espero que tenha ajudado.

*NOTA: Se não tiver permissão nos arquivos e pastas, não vai funcionar para determinados objetos.*

Comment: nossa era isso mesmo que queria. obrigado.

Comment: vou ver sim sobre a biblioteca

Comment: Se não for feita uma chamada  `f.flush()` entre o passo de gravar nḿeros aleatórios e o de gravar 0s, é como se o primeiro passo nem existisse - os números aleatórios na maior parte dos casos, nem serão transferidos para o disco.

Comment: Outra coisa: `                    for _ in range(data):
                        f.write(b'\x00')` é ineficiente nota 15, numa escala que vai de 0 até 10: esão sendo feitas duas mudanças de contexto da aplicação Python para cada _byte_ do arquivo - se for um arquivo de 1GB, pode esperar algumas horas. 
O correto aí é `f.write(b'\x00' * len(data)) ` ( claro, para arquivos da ordem de GB, melhor escrever uma estratégia que faça isso em blocos, mas são algumas poucas linhas)

Comment: jsbueno sim é verdade. Arquivos grandes a performance do script seria uma pausa imensa. Não percebi isso no script dele.

Comment: entao tenho que tirar o for _ in range(data): f.write(b'\x00'), ele não precisa? tentei colocar o * len(data) pq sao tipos diferentes.

Answer (score 3):

Gravar dados por cima dos dados de um arquivo não é "seguro" - e o motivo é que depende da camada de filesystem (F.S.) do sistema operacional decidir o que fazer quando você abre um arquivo para escrita  -  e se você for ver, nenhum deles, por vários motivos, vai gravar os dados na mesma posição física do disco em que os dados anteriores estavam.

A ideia de que ao abrir um arquivo para leitura e escrita, você pode modificar um único byte do arquivo, fechar, e ler de novo e ter todos os dados originais com aquele 1 byte diferente, é conveniente para programas em alto nível, mas é só uma abstração do sistema operacional.

Na prática, por conta de como o acesso a dados em disco evoluiu históricamente, o sistema só consegue escrever blocos de, no mínimo, 512 bytes - mas mais provavelmente 4Kbytes (4096) de uma vez - o que é feito quando você modifica um único byte é:
 - as camadas mais baixo nível do S.O. leem 4KB do disco (mesmo que o arquivo seja menor, qualquer sujeira que esteja no disco depois do arqiuvo é lida pra memória)
 - a camada de mais alto nível do S.O. alterar o byte desejado, dentro desse bloco
 - os 4KB são colocados de volta no disco, mas não na mesma posição
 - se tudo correu bem até aqui, a camada de F.S. do sistema operacional altera os metadados do arquivo para lerem os 4KB da nova posição, não da antiga. (principalmente em F.S. modernos que tem um mencanismo de journaling - que permite justamente que  a versão antiga do arquivo seja lida, se acontecer qualquer falha antes do final do processo todo).

Qualquer ferramenta que tenha acesso aos dados brutos na partição de disco pode então acessar os dados de arquivos "sobre-escritos". Pode dar um bom trabalho reconstruir esses arquivos a partir dos pedaços achados - e muitas partes podem sim estar fisicamente sobre-escritas, pelo próprio processo de re-escrever os arquivos, mas é mais ao "acaso" do que destruição deliberada.

Se você eestiver num sistema operacional Linux, os dados brutos da partição são acessíveis simplesmente se abrindo os dispositivos especiais em `/dev/` como se forem arquivos normais. (Nesse caso, ler e escrever nesses arquivos de dispositivo, *sim*, faz os bytes serem lidos e escritos nas mesmas posições físicas do disco - justamente por que o código de filesystem usado pelo kernel para acessar os dispositivos físicos como arquivos faz isso)

Então, se você tiver alguma bibliotca especial, que consiga entender as estrutura de dados do filesystem particular que você pretende alterar, é possível, com acsso ao dispositivo "bruto" (raw), sobre-escrever os bytes exatos, de forma irreversível, dos arquivos, como vocẽ deseja.

O trabalho pra fazer isso de forma correta é pelo menos uma ordem de grandeza mais complexo do que só usar a camada de usuário de abrir e gravar arquvos, como você quer fazer. (alguns filesystems são tão complexos, que dezenas dos melhores devs do mundo levaram mais de 10 anos para acessar seus dados diretamente de forma correta numa implementação paralela - veja o histórico dos drivers de NTFS no Linux, por exemplo, ou o ZFS). Mas se for uma FAT, ou FAT 32 - ainda usado em alguns drives USB, é mais ou menos tranquilo refazer o acesso, e pode ser um projeto bem divertido. (Mas em drives USB, não sei não se a camada de low-level, de firmware do dispositivo, não remapeia os blocos - ou seja, para qualquer acesso em software, sim, os dados estão "sobre-escritos" - mas pode ser que fisicamente ainda estejam lá - em discos SSD, *com certeza* isso acontece)

Acredito que quanto a sobre-escrever os arquivos recursivamente, as outras respostas aqui já dão conta - então não vou acrescentar ainda um outro exemplo de como fazer.

Comment: Nossa obrigado por esse texto cheio de conhecimento. então seria melhor eu ñ usar essa forma de gravar os dados que usei e sim apenas criptografar os arquivo?

Comment: criptografar os arquivos não adianta nada, nesse contexto: os dados criptografados vão ser escritos numa posição diferente do disco, e o conteúdo original vai estar lá pra quem acessar o dispositivo diretamente.
Criptografar direto o HD, sim, é algo que todos os sistemas operacionais hoje permitem, e, sem digitar a senha correta na hora de ligar o computador, não tem como ler.

Comment: Já, para dificultar o acesso - sem ir ao ponto de sobre-escrever os dados na camada física do disco, gravar um arquivo de mesmo nome na mesma pasta, e depois apaga-lo, é o suficiente: com isso alguém só com uma ferramenta de olhar os metadados do filesystem para "desapagar" um arquivo, vai chegar na posição errada.  Mas você também deve  apagar os caches do sistema operacioal, e cuidar para que mecanismos como o "time machinne" do Mac OS não tenham cópias de versões anteriores do arquivo.

Comment: Entendiiii. E no caso de Linux, apagar os caches...tem como?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode ler os arquivos do diretório corrente usando os.listdir('.') ou indicar o diretório que quer ler.

Outra forma é usando glob.glob('*.dat') onde a resposta seria uma lista de arquivos, neste caso do exemplo, com extensão ".dat".

A entrada da função poderia ser a lista de arquivos e tratava todos com um "for" ou poderia fazer um "for" e usar a função para cada arquivo.

Se quiser ver arquivos de subdiretórios pode considerar usar a função "os.walk".

Answer (score 1):

Tenho um script que exclui todos aquivos das pastas de cache do Windows, creio que isso pode te ajudar.

```
import os 
import win32con, win32api

list = ['C:\Windows\Prefetch','C:\Windows\Temp']

def clear_data(locate):
    for raiz, diretorios, arquivos in os.walk(locate):
        for arquivo in arquivos:
            try:
                print(arquivo)
                win32api.SetFileAttributes(os.path.join(raiz,arquivo), win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL)
                os.remove(os.path.join(raiz,arquivo))
            except:
                print(arquivo+' Erro')


temp = os.getenv('temp')
temp = temp.replace('Roaming','\Local\Temp')
list.append(temp)


for i in list:
    clear_data(i)

exit()
```

Comment: Entendi...mas a função que eu fiz será que ela faz a mesma coisa que o srm, ou shred? Tipo, abrir o arquivo e gravar dados binarios nele para não ser recuperado?

Comment: A que apresentei apenas exclui arquivos de cache de algumas pastas como temp e prefetch.

Comment: dentro do try voce pode alterar tudo aquilo para um objeto contendo a sua função e setar no LIST o diretorio que você quer excluir

Comment: Hum, tendi. Mas mesmo q eu consiga fazer isso, eu precisaria saber a forma de deixar o arquivo irrecuperavel e ilegivel, se agora forma funciona. Vou pegar sua dica pra deixr recursivo

Comment: Eu faria o seguinte.
Transformaria o arquivo em um TXT alterando sua extensão.
Em seguida utilizaria uma lib para encryptar o conteudo do txt utilizando uma hash difícil.
salvaria em txt e após isso excluiria o arquivo.

Comment: Humm, não tinha pensado nisso. Obrigado :)

Comment: e voce quer só destruir o arquivo, nao repcisa "encriptar" o arquivo - só sobre-escrever já faz tudo.
Outra coisa: a extenção de um arquivo não faz a menor diferença para libs, ou para programas rodando, é só uma dica (no caso do windows, para o sistema operacional - no caso do Unix, uma dica mais só para os usuários) de qual programa deve abrir aquele arquivo. O conteúdo em bytes de um arquivo lido não muda qualquer extensão que ele tenha.

Comment: Mas então - @WillianJesusDaSilva - espero que tenha entendido a ideia de nem precisar criptografar - dados aleatorios são ainda melhores, e de que a extensão não faz a menor diferença. Posto isso, a sua lembrança de excluir os arquivos de cache do sistema é bem pertinente - vou deixar um upvote por conta disso.